# the difference between 90° and 30° is 60°. then why is sine60° not equal to sine90°- sine30°?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

**The** difference between 90° and 30° is 60°. then why is sine60° not equal to sine90°- sine30°?

Comment: The difference between $5$ and $3$ is $2$. Then why is $2^2$ not equal to $5^2-3^2$?

Comment: Because $\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)-\sin(y)$ is not true.

Comment: $\sin$ is not a *linear* function, which may not be a satisfying answer, just repackaging the question into a form that has a common name. However, the most satisfying answer is probably just to compute what $\sin 90^\circ$ $\sin 30^\circ$, and $\sin 60^\circ$ are, and convince yourself they aren't equal. There is no reason that $\sin$ should be linear, a priori. Indeed many many functions are not linear.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sine is not a linear function.

Comment: But $\sin0+\sin1=\sin(0+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $\sin60^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$, but $\sin90^{\circ}-\sin30^{\circ}=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

and the contradiction in math does not exist.

Comment: Yes, but why is that? The difference between both points is still 60 degrees.

To be clear, I was asked to find the distance between a rotation that began at 90° to 30°. My instinct was to find the difference between the two (60°) then find the sine. What was wrong in my train of thought?

Comment: @ Omar E. See my post. This is the answer.